# Where is stored the "Encryption Fingerprint" for the "Remote Desktop" configuration?

Tags: server, encryption, remote-desktop, remote

For Ubuntu Desktop **22.04** - to allow a *Remote Desktop* connection, in the client side can be use `Remmina` and in the server is mandatory enable the `Remote Desktop` option, it through `Settings` -> `Sharing`.

In the bottom of the `Remote Desktop` window exists the `Authentication` section and the `Verify Encryption` button. If it is press it appears a small window with the `Encryption Fingerprint` value - it in the server side. For the client side - this value appears for the first attempt connection as a `Certificate`. Is mandatory accept that Certificate to accomplish the *first* connection and make others in the future.

**Question**

- From where does `Encryption Fingerprint` come from?

Or in other words:

- In what file is stored that `Encryption Fingerprint`?

That value shown is stored from some place (file), right?

Comment: I believe the fingerprint is the fingerprint of the certificate on the remote server, to validate the certificate properly.  If you don't know that fingerprint you have to get it from the remote system,.

Comment: Yes, it is about the **server**, where is enabled the `Remote Desktop` configuration - now, according with your comment : What is the `Certificate` name and where is stored? - I mean, something like `ssh` where the server has many public keys in `/etc/ssh` directory and with `ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf ssh_host_XXX_key.pub` can be retrieved the same `Fingerprint` **format**. Therefore both - ssh and this mentioned -  have the same `md5` format

Comment: That I don't know, it depends on the remote server.  Is the server Windows or Linux?  If it's Windows you'll have to ask on Super User.  You might want to do an insecure connection first, get the certificate fingerprint, then put that fingerprint in the security value.  The fingerprint is representative in HEX format though I believe not MD5 form.

Comment: The remote server is Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 as I indicated in the OP - because it is where is configured the `Remote Desktop`